# Own hostname not resolved, but DNS works

Tags: macos, networking, mac, dns, ping

Following problem on my Mac Mini:

- `hostname` brings: `macmini`
- `ping macmini` brings: `cannot resolve macmini: Unknown host`

Same on other computers in the network: ping with this name does not work, ping with IP of this computer works.

IP overall works, ping by name to other computer in my network works. DNS works also, the problem is only with the own hostname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you want to start overriding your DNS settings (or editing a host file), you'll need to get used to addressing your local machine with the *.local* TLD.

[image: screenshot of Sharing Preferences]
As you can see in my screenshot, my machine's name is "intrepid". Below the name it states the local name is "intrepid.local".

This isn't really a problem, but more of a property.

Try pinging *macmini.local*.

Comment: @ralf don't forget to check mark the answer if this is what solved your problem.